# phpmyadmin query not completing using SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL query for calculating the 5 year moving average for some fishing data:

```
SELECT
a.species,
a.date,
a.qty_taken,
(   
SELECT SUM(b.qty_taken) / COUNT(b.qty_taken)
FROM global AS b
WHERE species = a.species
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.date, b.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
)   AS '5_yr_avg'
FROM global AS a
WHERE a.species IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.species, a.date DESC;
```

When I run the query in PHPMyAdmin it returns a result in about 14.6 seconds.

But when I try to run it over SSH it is not completing (returning a result)?

Would welcome any ideas on what might be preventing the query from completing over SSH?

A JOIN query used to create the table this query uses executes and returns a result. Which makes me think there is a problem with the query itself and that I just can't see it...

The Shell code looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> a.species,
    -> a.date
    -> a.qty_taken,
    -> (SELECT SUM(b.qty_taken) / COUNT(b.qty_taken)
    -> FROM global AS b
    -> WHERE species = a.species
    ->  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.date, b.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
    -> )AS '5_yr_avg'
    -> FROM global AS a
    -> WHERE a.species IS NOT NULL
    -> ORDER BY a.species, a.date DESC;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    27774465
Current database: j2_possbil
```

Comment: Show how you run this script via ssh.

Comment: What happens if you try your ssh script with a very simple query? If you still get no results then its the script and not the query. ie : show the script

Comment: @Thomas yes, something like show tables or SELECT * FROM Table_a works

Comment: @Cyrus - shell code at the bottom of the question. The cursor is sitting on the next line - so understand it to be executing

Comment: The warning "ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away" is assumed to be because no persistent DB and not the cause of the problem.  ISP gave no indication of it being otherwise, but have not pressed them on it.

Comment: how long does it take between submitting the query via the mysql commandline (ssh is probably irrelevant) and getting the error back?

Comment: the error is instant